# How to redirect custom post type posts to one url with htaccess?

Tags: custom-post-types, redirect

I have a custom post type "products". I would like to redirect all posts from "products" to one url ex: http://example.com/page1 using htaccess.

For example:
http://example.com/products/post1, http://example.com/products/post2 and http://example.com/products/post3 to be on link click redirected to one page http://example.com/page1

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^products/(.*)$ /http://example.com/page1 [R=301,L]

I cant find this topic anywhere. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/90098) from Webmaster StackExchange might be helpful:

```
RewriteRule ^products/ /page1/ [R=301,L]
```

Goes after the `RewriteEngine` and `RewriteBase` rules, but above all the other WordPress stuff.

If you don't want to fiddle with the `.htaccess`, you can have a look at the [Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) plugin.